# How to use jOOQ to correctly generate date and time types with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, jooq

According to SQLite documentation it is possible to store dates and times in columns with TEXT, REAL or INTEGER affinity.
For clarity, I would choose TEXT.

I would expect jOOQ to generate String fields.
How is it possible to have jOOQ correctly generate JSR-310 java.time (`LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime`) types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell jOOQ's code generator to rewrite your data types:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites

Use the type names from [`SQLDataType`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/SQLDataType.html), for example:

```xml
<forcedTypes>
  <forcedType>
    <name>LOCALDATE</name>
    <includeExpression>DATE_COLUMN</includeExpression>
  </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```